# Cannot resolve reference in visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I have a custom object named: Digest. I have another custom object named: Interesting_Fact.
A User can have many Digests. And a Digest can have many interesting facts.   I am sending out information about digests and interesting facts to all users in emails using a Visual force template.

In my visual force template I pull in Digest by doing:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Daily Digest" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Digest__c">
```

This works.

However, I want to display a table for all the interest facts for each digest. I do:

```
<table border="1">
<tr >
    <th>Opportunity</th><th>Interesting Fact</th>
</tr>
    <apex:repeat var="fact" value="{!relatedTo.Interesting_Facts__c}">
    ...
```

But I get:

```
Error: Invalid field DM_Interesting_Facts__c for SObject Digest__c
```

I relationship is defined as a lookup, from Interesting_fact to Digest.  I 
check this relationship and it tell me:

```
Child Relationship Name:    Interesting_Facts
```

So I can't understand how I get this error. I also try, Interesting_Facts i.e. removing __c but this gives same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `__r` instead of `__c`? Generally speaking - experiment with form that would be also a valid subquery, I suspect `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Interesting_Facts__r) FROM Digest__c LIMIT 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referencing **DM_**Interesting_Facts__c  in your page /controller somewhere ?

I see that the name is Interesting_Facts__c

/try using Interesting_Facts__r since it is a related object use

Answer (score 2):

From your Eclipse find the Child relationship name and use the same here.

[image]

The Call is My Parent Object and Call_Detail__c my child Objects.Observe the arrows and we get the Child relationship name .

Use Childnrelationship Name Properly to resolve this.

Comment: I am newbie. Can you tell me how you brought up that dialog?

Comment: 1)Install eclipse

Comment: Have eclipse installed but can't see that dialog under the force.com options.

Comment: Link does not work.

Comment: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.3.x